# It gives error since I closed the scanner in main method but I created a new scanner in the method

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

i tried to creating a new scanner after i closed the former in the main. but it gives error.
i thought that i created a new scanner in the method than i closed it so it would read the new inputs through my method but it did not. what is the issue here? chatgpt couldn't illuminate me :(

```
package gross_calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrossPayCalculator {
    
    static void story() {
        
        System.out.println("Which season the day is of?");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String season = scanner1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How is that day?");
        String adjective = scanner1.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What is the number?");
        int number = scanner1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("On a "+adjective+" "+season+" day,\nyou read "+number+" pages of book.");
        scanner1.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int hours = 0;
        System.out.println("How many hours did you work?: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        hours = scanner.nextInt();
        
        double payRate = 0;
        System.out.println("What is your pay rate?: ");
        payRate = scanner.nextDouble();
        
        scanner.close();
        
        double grossPay = hours*payRate;
        System.out.println("Gross pay: "+grossPay);
        
        story();
    }

}
```

error message:

```
How many hours did you work?: 
23
What is your pay rate?: 
12,2
Gross pay: 280.59999999999997
Which season the day is of?
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at java_essentials/gross_calculator.GrossPayCalculator.story(GrossPayCalculator.java:11)
    at java_essentials/gross_calculator.GrossPayCalculator.main(GrossPayCalculator.java:36)
```

Comment: What is the error it is giving you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single `Scanner` object, and don't close it since you are reading from `System.in`

*See the comments on this answer for further clarification.*

```
package gross_calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GrossPayCalculator {

    private static void printStory(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("Which season is it?");
        String season = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How is the day?");
        String adjective = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a number:");
        int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println("On a " + adjective + " " + season + " day, you read " + number + " pages of a book.");
    }

    private static double calculateGrossPay(Scanner scanner) {
        System.out.println("How many hours did you work?: ");
        int hours = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println("What is your hourly pay rate?: ");
        double payRate = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
        return hours * payRate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double grossPay = calculateGrossPay(scanner);
        System.out.println("Gross pay: " + grossPay);
        printStory(scanner);
    }
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
How many hours did you work?: 
8
What is your hourly pay rate?: 
100
Gross pay: 800.0
Which season is it?
Spring
How is the day?
Sunny
Enter a number:
42
On a Sunny Spring day, you read 42 pages of a book.
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is not possible to use two scanners?

Comment: It's not about the scanner, it's about `System.in`. When closing the scanner, you are also closing the underlying stream (`System.in`), which means that you will never be able to read from `System.in` until your application is restarted.

Comment: @Slevin you can use however many scanners you would like to, but there's only 1 `System.in` so makes sense to only have 1 Scanner object reading from that stream.  It just creates unnecessary overhead.  And Scanners need to be closed when no longer used and if you close a Scanner, you are closing `System.in` and your other Scanners will fail like the OP has a problem with.

Comment: Thanks for this explanations vatbub, Keith Russo. This information should be added to the answer since a solution without underlying explanation of the why is imo not worth much. Thanks

Comment: @Slevin Feel free to edit the answer, integrating what you think would be relevant for future readers from the above two comments; I'll approve.

Comment: "*you can use however many scanners you would like*"  can be a problem if the scanners do cache some input...